# What's the opposite of [F] (i.e. forbid) in Apache's .htaccess syntax?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

I have a rule that's applied to my Apache's httpd.conf configuration which looks like:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/.*/\..*/">
    Order deny,allow    
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

It blocks access to hidden directories such as .git in our webroot. However, the web application we're using (Magento) makes use of a .thumbs sub-directory within the media directory that needs to be publicly accessible.

I have a rule that works in .htaccess that explicitly *forbids* access to hidden directories:

```
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

But I can't seem to find the *allows* version of of the above line.

Context: The reason we're not modifying the Apache httpd.conf configuration file is that we're hoping to resolve this with only a code-based deployment and side-step the need to reload the web server's configuration on each lifecycle environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...not modifying the Apache `httpd.conf` configuration file

**tl;dr** Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the directory you want to allow access, ie. `/media/.thumbs/.htaccess`:

```
<Files "*">
    Order deny,allow    
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

---

> What's the opposite of [F] (i.e. forbid) ...

You seem to be asking the wrong question. You need the opposite of `Deny` (mod_authz_host) - it is this that you need to override. (However, there are further complications with the order in which the directives are processed, so read on...)

(*Aside:* The `F` flag is mod_rewrite's way of sending a 403 Forbidden response, there isn't really an *opposite* of this, other than to avoid sending a 403 Forbidden! If the request is already blocked with mod_authz_host (ie. `Deny`) then you can't "undo" this with mod_rewrite.)

The opposite of `Deny` is `Allow` in mod_authz_host. For example, in the `/media/.thumbs/.htaccess` file, you could do this:

```
Order deny,allow    
Allow from all
```

However, this won't override the `<DirectoryMatch>` container in the server config, becuase `<DirectoryMatch>` containers are processed *after* `.htaccess`. If, however, you had used a (non-regex) `<Directory>` container in the server config, instead of `<DirectoryMatch>`, then this would have overridden the server config because `<Directory>` containers and `.htaccess` are processed at the *same time* with `.htaccess` overriding `<Directory>` containers.

HOWEVER, you can still allow access to all the *files* within the `/media/.thumbs` subdirectory by wrapping the above `Allow` directives in a `<Files>` container (in the same `.htaccess` file). For example:

```
<Files "*">
    Order deny,allow    
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

By wrapping these directives in a `<Files>` container you are changing the order of processing. Crucially, `<Files>` containers are processed *after* `<DirectoryMatch>` containers (despite it appearing in the `.htaccess` file), so this now overrides the `<DirectoryMatch>` container in the server config.

From [the Apache 2.2 docs on how sections are merged](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin):

> The order of merging is:
>
> 1. `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) and `.htaccess` done simultaneously (with .htaccess, if allowed, overriding `<Directory>`)
> 2. `<DirectoryMatch>` (and `<Directory ~>`)
> 3. `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` done simultaneously
> 4. `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` done simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

1º Don't use .htaccess

2º Add a regex "negative lookahead" before the actual pattern to make an exception:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/(?!\.thumbs).*/\..*/>
    Order deny,allow    
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !"path to.thumbs sub-directory"
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

To block the access on all folders except the specified folder.

Comment: However, this won't override the server config that already blocks these requests. It's this server-override that seems to be the requirement here.